# kafka stream with exactly_once enabled generate several duplicated messages

Tags: apache-kafka, stream, apache-kafka-streams, eos, read-committed

Kafka stream with exactly_once enabled generate several duplicated messages with (not committed transaction status)

I did a tests in my pc :

- without "exactly_once"
  for 100_000 messages, I got  100_000 on topic target.
- with props.put(PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, "exactly_once");
  for 100_000 messages, I got  100_554 on target topic.
  For this last one consuming the topic target with "read_committed" allow to read only 100_000 messages.
  But the remaining 554 pollute the flow monitoring.

Is there a reason to have more 554 messages when activating "exactly_once" option ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The 554 messages are most likely the transaction markers that are needed to provide exactly-once delivery semantics.

When you use exactly-once, Kafka Streams uses Kafka transactions to write records to the output topics. Kafka transactions use transaction markers to mark whether records were part of a committed or an aborted transaction.

A consumer with isolation level `read_commited` interprets the transaction markers to decide which records to skip because they were part of an aborted transactions and which records to return in calls to `poll()` because they were part of a committed transaction.